# Поиск подстроки в ключах словаря

Tags: golang, поиск

Имеется некий словарь `string -> V`. Суть задачи в том, чтобы для заданной подстроки, назовем ее `search`, найти все `V`, у каждого из которых `search` является подстрокой для ключа этого `V`.

Какие существуют алгоритмы или способы эффективного решения данной задачи (например с предобработкой ключей)?

В интернете нашел только информацию о поиске нескольких подстрок в одной строке, но в моем случае задача обратная: поиск нескольких строк по одной подстроке.

Так же нашел сложные реализации подобного поиска на Go, но для целых документов, что выглядит слишком тяжелым для этой задачи

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyFvEECgsWs

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/index/suffixarray

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576284/998126

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov встроенная библиотека suffixarray не подходит при поиске подстроки из множества строк. Разве что можно множество строк объединить в одну с разделяющими спецсимволами, но я уже нашел более удобный способ

Answer (score 0):

В итоге в качестве решения выбрал поиск из множества ключей с помощью триграмм.

Выбор пал на библиотеку https://github.com/dgryski/go-trigram, позволяющую искать строки из массива строк по их частичному совпадению. Естественно для решения задачи необходимо ключи словаря преобразовать в массив ключей, так как библиотека возвращает индексы этого массива